# Data request is only returning address value (I2C)

Tags: c, protocols, avr, i2c

I'm trying to read some values being returned by a sensor device. It is all hooked up fine, but I'm struggling to retrieve data from the sensor, properly.

In the [datasheet](https://ams.com/eng/content/download/686523/1787697/file/iAQ-core_Datasheet_EN_v1.pdf) it says that I should receive bytes in the order: prediction, status, resistance, tvoc.

My terminal keeps spitting out the same value, 23130 (0x5a5a)

This leads me to believe that I'm not properly calling my `i2c_start()`. [In the protocol readme](https://github.com/g4lvanix/I2C-master-lib) it says to read with `I2C_start(SLAVE_READ_ADDRESS);'` I tried replacing the address with the so-called *read starting point* being 0xB5, but that returns my error.

```
/* Name: main.c
 * Author: <insert your name here>
 * Copyright: <insert your copyright message here>
 * License: <insert your license reference here>
 */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <i2c_master.h>

#define LED PB5

#define I2C_READ 0x5A

char buffer[10];

uint16_t val = 0;
uint16_t pred = 0;
uint8_t status = 0;
uint8_t resistance = 0;
uint8_t tvoc = 0;


void getVal()
{
  if(i2c_start(I2C_READ))
    {
        //uart_puts("Start ");

        val = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;
        val |= i2c_read_ack();

      pred = ((uint16_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;
      pred |= i2c_read_ack();

      // status = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;
      // status |= i2c_read_ack();

      // resistance = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;
      // resistance |= i2c_read_ack();

      // tvoc = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8;
      // tvoc |= i2c_read_nack();

      i2c_stop();

    } else
  {
        uart_puts("Error");

        i2c_stop();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  init_uart(57600);
  i2c_init();

  DDRB = _BV(5);

    for(;;)
    {

      getVal();

      itoa(val, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
      uart_puts(buffer);
      uart_puts(" ");

            itoa(pred, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
      uart_puts(buffer);
      uart_puts(" ");

      itoa(status, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
      uart_puts(buffer);
      uart_puts(" ");

      itoa(resistance, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
      uart_puts(buffer);
      uart_puts(" ");

      itoa(tvoc, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
      uart_puts(buffer);
      uart_puts(" ");

      PORTB = 0xFF;
      _delay_ms(500);
      PORTB = 0x00;
      _delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;   /* never reached */
}
```

Comment: Most of the variables where you shift 8 bits and OR the next byte are of type `uint8_t`. So that's not going to work.

Comment: Okay I will increase the buffer size! What am I doing wrong otherwise?

Comment: Ooops I misread when I typed the last comment. `char buffer[4];` will only be large enough for 3-digits decimal numbers.

Comment: Plainly you need `uint16_t pred` and such as `pred = ((uint16_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8; pred |= i2c_read_ack();`

Comment: Now terminal outputs 23130 23130 23130 23130 23130

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet is very unclear and contains a fault as far as addressing is concerned. The address for WRITING is 0xB4 and the address for READING is 0xB5.

The datasheet says the address is:

```
BIT    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0
DATA   1    0    1    1    0    1    0   R/W
```

which corresponds to 0xB4 or 0xB5 depending on the R/W bit beeing set or not. The error they make in the text is that (0)1011010 is 0x5A but the R/W bit is the least significant bit, not the most significant bit.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but calling i2c_start(0xB4) throws my error

Comment: You need 0xB5... Because you are reading data from the device.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that 0xB5 throws that error. I actually tested both, though.

Comment: There are other errors with your code, such as this `val = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8` - shifting uint8_t 8 bits left yields 0. Try printing the individual bytes first to check if they arrive correctly.

Comment: WeatherVane mentioned that one. As you suggested, I'm now only checking `uint16_t val = 0;` which prints `23130`

Comment: When do I implement this shift? Changing the address results in an error.

Comment: @user1320881: Its pretty common (and essentially correct) that they refer to the right aligned 7-bit value (without the R/W bit) as the address in I2C devices data sheets. The byte-value may be the "address byte" with respect to the protocol, but not the address.

Comment: But they mix both ways of stating the address when they talk about reading or writing which is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The i2c_start function in the i2cmaster library returns 1 to indicate an error, not zero

```
uint8_t i2c_start(uint8_t address)
{
    // ... snip ...

    // check if the device has acknowledged the READ / WRITE mode
    uint8_t twst = TW_STATUS & 0xF8;
    if ( (twst != TW_MT_SLA_ACK) && (twst != TW_MR_SLA_ACK) ) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

So in your `getVal` function, you should have

```
void getVal()
{
  if(i2c_start(I2C_READ) == 0) // 0 indicates success
    {
```

In addition, I can't see why you're reading two 16-bit values `val` and `pred` from the sensor. The datasheet indicates that `pred` is the first value returned. You should also read the 8-bit `status` value to check if the data read is valid.